# How to Run Batch File when the Active Window is Fullscreen (and on Exit Fullscreen)

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, automation, fullscreen

As the title states, I want to write a script that detects when a program enters or exits fullscreen; these two triggers will then run one of two .bat files that start or stop the Rainmeter.exe process.

*The goal is to automatically shut down Rainmeter when a game is launched in fullscreen, freeing up CPU resources, and then re-activate Rainmeter upon fullscreen exit.*

The issue is, I'm not sure how to detect whether the active window is fullscreen or not, and I've had no luck searching the web thus far. Is there a flag I can check, or a specific line in a log I can check? Can this be done using Windows Task Scheduler?

I know it is possible because the ControllerCompanion program (turns a controller into a mouse) automatically de/re-activates when a program enters/exits fullscreen. Can I possibly piggy-back on this functionality?

I'm comfortable with Batch, Python, and Javascript, and ready to learn any new languages to make this work, just looking for a point in the right direction!

*As an aside point of interest:* I've come across conflicting answers on what "fullscreen" means; As I understood, a "fullscreen" program takes total control of the display, whereas "fullscreen windowed" draws the program window over the desktop, filling the screen. Is this correct? Or is the desktop drawn under the fullscreen window in both cases (which means they are both the same)?

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a hard challenge to solve your problem.

Luckily this is a classical X-Y problem. You have a problem, thought of a solution, and now you are seeking help for that solution. The problem here is that your solution is not the most practical and easy to execute one is.

Instead, I would create a batch file for every game you want to work with. That batch file stops rainmeter, then launches the game, wait for the game to exit, then starts rainmeter, then exit.

You can basically create 1 batch file and use the executable as parameter, then edit all the shortcuts to your batchfile with the original shortcut as parameter.

An example of what such batchfile would be:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Stop Rainmeter
    stoprainmeter.cmd

::  -- Change to the folder the game is stored in
    cd /d %~dp1

::  -- Launch the game
    start /wait "%1"

::  -- Start Rainmeter
    startrainmeter.cmd
```

You doubleclick the game, and it does not matter if your game is full-screen or not, it closes rainmeter, launches the game, and once the game exits, the batchfile will run rainmeter.

To answer your last question: A full screen game vs windowed no border type of fullscreen are indeed quite different. A fullscreen game will create a new virtual space and moves the view port to that virtual space. As such there is no desktop behind it and going into the fullscreen mode and exiting out of it takes a bit of time. A windowed no-border kind of fullscreen draws over the desktop to make it appear to be full-screen, but any windowed app that has the always on-top flag active, may be drawn over it, and if you use a program to make any window semi-transparent, and use that for your game, you will be able to see your desktop through it, whereas with a true fullscreen mode, you will not.